# Neo4j Excluding nodes from result

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am quite new to Neo4j and Graph.

I have a simple Graph database with just one relationship: table -[contains]-> column

I'm trying to get a list of tables and columns that contain a specific term in their name.

I want to show that as a list of Tables and a count of columns for that table. If the table name does not contain the term but one of it columns does, then it should be in the list. Also, the count of columns should only include columns that contain the term.

Here is an example:

```
Table: "Chicago", Columns: "Chi_Address", "Chi_Weather", "Latitude"
Table: "Miami"  , Columns: "Mia_to_Chi", "Mia_Weather"
Table: "Dallas" , Columns: "Dal_to_Mia", "Dal_Weather"
```

If I search for the term "chi", the desired result would be:

```
Table   -- Col Count
Chicago -- 2
Miami   -- 1
```

This is my current query:

```
MATCH (t:table)-[r:contains]->(c:column) 
where toLower(t.name) contains toLower('CHI') or toLower(c.name) contains toLower('CHI')
return t.name as Table_Name,count(c.name) as Column_Count
```

My problem is that if a table contains the term, then I get a count of all its columns, not just the ones with the term. So I'm my example I would get

```
Chicago -- 3 //Instead of 2
Miami   -- 1
```

I was thinking of doing something like:

```
count(c.name WHERE c.name contains('CHI')
```

But that doesn't seem to be a valid syntax.

Any help would be appreciated.

PS: Happy to take any advice on how to improve my current query. For example, I'm sure that having the search term twice is something that I should improve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your approach isn't going to use an index lookup anyway, we might as well change the approach here.

We can start off by matching to all :table nodes, then OPTIONAL MATCH to all :column nodes with your CONTAINS predicate. When we `count()` the matches this will only include the column count where the CONTAINS check is true (in some cases it will be 0). So that gets our Column_Count correct.

Next we'll filter the results, only keeping rows where we found a positive Column_Count or where the CONTAINS check is true for the :table node.

```
MATCH (t:table)
OPTIONAL MATCH (t)-[:contains]->(c:column)
WHERE toLower(c.name) contains toLower('CHI')
WITH t, count(c) as Column_Count
WHERE Column_Count <> 0 OR toLower(t.name) contains toLower('CHI')
RETURN t.name as Table_Name, Column_Count
```

Comment: This worked great @InverseFalcon .  Thank you for your help! I had somehow got it to work using three different unions but it was unruly and 3 times longer than your code.

Not to be too picky, but I would like to now have 2 counts. One of columns containing the keyword and another one with the total count. I want to show something like "X out of Z columns match". I tried adding another optional match and working with adding another count(c) in differnet places but none seemed to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Got it working!
`MATCH (t:table)-[:contains]->(c:column)
WITH t, count(c) as Total_Column_Count
OPTIONAL MATCH (t)-[:contains]->(c:column)
WHERE toLower(c.name) contains toLower('CHI')
WITH  t,count(c) as Column_Count, Total_Column_Count
WHERE Column_Count > 0 OR toLower(t.name) contains toLower('CHI')
RETURN t.name as Table_Name, Column_Count, Total_Column_Count`
Any feedback on how to improve that code is appreciated. Also I was thinking on changing my question to make it more helpful, let me know if you reckon there's a better way to phrase the title.